# Forward port 8888

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding

I am on Linux ubuntu 12.04. I have internet connection on this system using WIFI.  I was wondering if it is possible to share my laptop port `8888` over wifi, so other devices on the same wifi connection will be able to access on this computer using `127.0.0.1:8585`(as if the host pc then listens 8888 in 8585 port.
). I am so very curious to know. Thanks, I do not have any router with my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want something like `ssh raki@ubuntu -L 8585:localhost:8888`

When you run this on your other computers it will open up a local port 8585 that get forwarded to port 8888 on your ubuntu machine.

But you mention that you have no router, so it is confusing... are your computers all on the same network?  Or they have no network at all and you want your ubuntu host to do the routing?

Comment: Thanks, actually my laptop has internet access from
a WiFi network, and my other devices are also connected on this WiFi network.

Comment: Ok great, then try out that ssh command and let me know if it does what you want.